# Restricting the term-document matrix to most frequent unigrams

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

The code below as an example for analyzing massive corpus. I want to restrict the term-document matrix to 1000 most frequent unigrams, but changing the `max-features` parameter to `n` only return the first `n` unigrams. Any suggestion?

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer 
import pandas as pd

corpus = ['Hi my name is Joe.', 'Hi my name is Donald.'] 
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=3) 
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).todense()
    
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names()) 
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that this is a problem in your example, but according to the sklearn documentation for `TfidfVectorizer` ssays the following for `max_features`:

> If not `None`, build a vocabulary that only consider the top `max_features` ordered by term frequency across the corpus.

It might be that the first `n` terms are considered when there are words of equal frequency, but otherwise it should return the correct result. If it still does not work, I strongly suggest to open a bug report in the sklearn repository. However, you can also manually construct a vocabulary yourself (with your own interpretation of "frequency", by setting the `vocabulary` option:

> `vocabulary`: Mapping or iterable, `default=None`
> Either a Mapping (e.g., a dict) where keys are terms and values are indices in the feature matrix, or an iterable over terms. If not given, a vocabulary is determined from the input documents.